# How to Send an Email in Development with Actionmailer Sendgrid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, development-environment, sendgrid

I'm having an impossible time trying to figure out how to setup email in development with sendgrid, and Actionmailer.

I've read a bunch of varying things and I keep getting different errors. Right now I get this one:

```html
Net::SMTPFatalError in UsersController#create
550 Cannot receive from specified address <noreply@example.com>: Unauthenticated senders not allowed
```

What do I need to put in development.rb so that the activation email is sent?

```html
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
:port           => '587',
:authentication => :plain,
:user_name      =>  ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
:password       =>  ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
:domain         => 'localhost:3000',
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

2

Comment: Can you confirm that your username and password are contained in the environment variables `SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `SENDGRID_PASSWORD`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the rails cast tutorial here because I couldn't get it to work with sendgrid: http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email-revised?view=asciicast

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just need to set the SENDGRID_USERNAME and SENDGRID_PASSWORD environment variables.  You can set these temporarily in your terminal by running the following commands:

```
export SENDGRID_USERNAME=<your sendgrid username>
export SENDGRID_PASSWORD=<your sendgrid password>
```

When you restart your terminal you will lose these settings. To make them persistent add those same commands to your ~/.bash_profile

Comment: SG Support here! "Unauthenticated senders not allowed" explicitly means that the code is not attempting to pass the username and password.